# mysql getting all not exists from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

Hi I've got 2 tables:
customers
invoices

I'd like to find all customers who hasn't bought from me monthly for the past 6 months. This is what I've got at the moment:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE invoices.customerid = customers.customerid AND month(invoices.fdate) = '2')
```

it kept running for 10 mins and there are still no results. i'm thinking that even if my syntax works, i'd have to go about it monthly, and crossing it off my customers table manually.

is there a better solution? all help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You query doesn't quite do what you want.  The correctly phrased one probably won't work any better:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM invoices i
                  WHERE i.customerid = c.customerid AND 
                        i.fdate >= CURDATE() - interval 6 month
                 );
```

For this version, you want an index on `invoices(customerid, fdate)`.

You might also give this a shot:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c JOIN
     (SELECT customerid, MAX(fdate) as max_fdate
      FROM invoices i
      GROUP BY customerid
     ) i
     ON i.customerid = c.customerid
WHERE i.max_fdate < CURDATE() - interval 6 month;
```

Comment: I did the index on both fields and tried the bottom solution. it ran for 2 mins and came back with a list of all customers who hasn't bought from me in the past 6 months. is it possible to get a list of customers who doesn't have at least 1 invoice per month within the last 6 months? Thanks

Comment: @AndrewTsang . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, along with sample data and desired results.  Although a careful reading of this question suggests that might be what you are asking, a clear question is desirable.